# PTRACE_SYSEMU, and PTRACE_SYSEMU_SINGLESTEP not defined on x64 or x86?

Tags: c, linux, ptrace

My code is as follows:

```
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main()
{
    printf("PTRACE_CONT: %d\n", PTRACE_CONT);
    printf("PTRACE_SYSCALL: %d\n", PTRACE_SYSCALL);
    printf("PTRACE_SINGLESTEP: %d\n", PTRACE_SINGLESTEP);
    printf("PTRACE_SYSEMU: %d\n", PTRACE_SYSEMU);
    printf("PTRACE_SYSEMU_SINGLESTEP: %d\n", PTRACE_SYSEMU_SINGLESTEP);
    printf("PTRACE_LISTEN: %d\n", PTRACE_LISTEN);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling with the default flags on Ubuntu16.04 (Linux x86_64 4.40-38), with gcc v5.4.0.

This throws an error that `PTRACE_SYSEMU` is undeclared. While the `man ptrace` page [states it exists](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html). This is repeated for `PTRACE_SYSEMU_SINGLESTEP` if the line containing `PTRACE_SYSEMU` is commented out. Which the man page states `PTRACE_SYSEMU_SINGLESTEP` is only available for x86, [except a patch was merged to unify the x86 and x64](https://lkml.org/lkml/2008/7/16/429) handling of `PTRACE_SYSEMU_SINGLESTEP` in 2008.

This produces the same error on 32bit (well i686), or 64bit (AMD64). Is this distro specific? What is going on?

I can confirm neither of these values are defined are in my `/usr/include/x86_64/linux/sys/ptrace.h`. But they are defined in kernel sources?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Ubuntu 16.04 (and also 14.04), these are defined in `<asm/ptrace-abi.h>`, which is included by `<asm/ptrace.h>`, which in turn is included by `<linux/ptrace.h>`, but not by `<sys/ptrace.h>`

Since these request codes are linux specific (not part of any standard), if you want them, you need to `#include <linux/ptrace.h>`

Comment: Thank you. I swear in my testing I attempted <linux/ptrace.h> I must have misspelled a variable and ran off painting yak sheds.

Answer (score 0):

Sysemu is used in user-mode linux as optimization and described at http://sysemu.sourceforge.net/ site. It is feature for UML (when special kernel runs as ordinary process) and not for typical users of `ptrace`.

Its implementation in x86 linux can be checked by `TIF_SYSCALL_EMU` flag in lxr of linux kernel (`ptrace_resume`)

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/ptrace.c?v=4.10#L767

```
767 static int ptrace_resume(struct task_struct *child, long request,
768                          unsigned long data)
   ...
780 #ifdef TIF_SYSCALL_EMU
781         if (request == PTRACE_SYSEMU || request == PTRACE_SYSEMU_SINGLESTEP)
782                 set_tsk_thread_flag(child, TIF_SYSCALL_EMU);
783         else
784                 clear_tsk_thread_flag(child, TIF_SYSCALL_EMU);
785 #endif
```

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=TIF_SYSCALL_EMU

The only definition is for x86:

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h?v=4.10#L85

```
 85 #define TIF_SYSCALL_EMU         6       /* syscall emulation active */
```

Comment: And patch to implement this for ARM is very simple at 2015: https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/6834311/